# Change colour on hover? Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have this code within my website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".service_body").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class menu_body
        $(".service_head").click(function(){
            $(this).next(".service_body").slideToggle(600); 
            var plusmin;
            plusmin = $(this).children(".plusminus").text();

            if( plusmin == ' ▾ ')
                $(this).children(".plusminus").text(' - ');
            else
                $(this).children(".plusminus").text(' ▾ ');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I just want it so when someone hovers over the ▾ (.plusminus) with their mouse pointer it changes colour to show its a link to expand the information.
I have been messing around for an hour or so now and not sure what to do? Any help would be very grateful

Comment: For a simple hover, better use css. `.plusminus:hover { color: green; }`

Comment: Can you please add the HMTL code that comes with this function?

Comment: Show you HTML code also

Comment: The last 2 .text() look like normal & happy smileys !

Comment: That's a fairly obvious duplicate of, for example, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107219/color-change-onhover). Did you search for similar questions before posting yours?

Answer (score 2):

It is better to solve it using CSS:

```css
.plusminus {color: blue;}
.plusminus:hover {color: red;}
```

For your query about expanded contents, you can use jQuery Tipsy to show some good tip.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery also to get this.

```
   $(".plusminus").hover(
     function() {
        $(this).addClass("greenClass");
     },
     function(){
        $(this).removeClass("greenClass");
     }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend CSS for this, like that :

```
.plusminus:hover{
    color:orange;
}
```

But you can also do it with Javascript, for example if you prefer to change color only if the item has a specific character :

```
$('.plusminus').mouseenter(function(){
    if($(this).text() == '  ▾  ') //Remove this line if you want to change the color for both characters.
        $(this).css({color: 'orange'});
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
});
```